# Binary search on a "dictionary" (two dimensional array)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, binary-search

Suppose we have `n` words and `n/k` "pages" (lets assume `n/k` is a natural number). So we have a "dictionary" which is actually an array of "pages" where each page is an array too and has `k` words.

The words are sorted in a way such that all the words in page `i` are lexicographically smaller than the words in page `i+1`, but **the words in each page aren't sorted**.

I need to write a method for finding a specific word in the "dictionary". I know I should use a binary search to find the right page, but I'm not so sure how because the words in each page aren't sorted.

what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know what the sorted first/last word on each page is then a binary search can only find what pair of pages may contain the word.

If the "top" word in a page comes before the word you want then you can eliminate all pages before that, but not *that* page; there could be another word further down the page that comes after your word.

If the top word in a page comes after the word you want, then you can eliminate all the pages after that, but not *that* page; there could be another word further down the page that comes before your word.

So when you finish your binary search you'll be left with two pages; page *N* whose top word is less than the one you want, and page *N+1* whose top word is greater than the word you want.

You then have to do a linear search across both pages to find the word.

Comment: So what is the right "halt-condition" I should use in that case? Is it `right - left == 1`?

Comment: Yes, that would be appropriate. Don't forget to handle the case where the word you want is the "top" word.